# slick.js drag not working with fullpage.js scrollOverflow: true

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js, slick.js, iscroll

I am building a site using fullpage.js with scrollOverflow option set to true and implementing a slick.js in a section which is longer than the viewport height.

The left click drag does not work on slick.js when the IScroll is initialized. It should be noted that right click and middle click (mouse) drag works fine, so I'm presuming the event is either stopped from propagating or something similar.

It works fine when the section in question is smaller than the viewport height.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to play a bit with the fullPage.js option  `scrollOverflowOptions`. See the [iScroll docs](http://iscrolljs.com/) for more info.

Comment: See the defaults used by fullPage.js [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/vendors/scrolloverflow.js#L2331).